# Where is the best place to check permissions of an object?

Tags: design-patterns, laravel-4

I am using Laravel for my app and I would like to ask where is the best place to check permissions of an object.

Each model has checkPermissions() method.

So if user make a request to change model client router will call method updateClient() in controller. Should I do it like this:

```
$client = Client::find(Input::get('id'));
$client->checkPermissions();
```

or should I create a new method for getting client and check permission inside it? :

```
$client = Client::getClientById($id);
```

where getClientById() is method defined on Client model and it check permissions...

Can you describe also why you choose one or another solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single 'best place'. It will depend on your application.

But there are realistically two options.

1. In a filter. That way you can filter the request before it hits your controller, and ensure they have access to the record they are trying to access
2. In the controller, using the example you have given above.

It is not a good idea to do auth checking inside the model - the model should only be focused on getting the data, not doing auth.

Answer (score 0):

you can define the access mechanism using a **template step** (check permission and then access data from inside your controller)..I agree w/ @theshiftchange that model should not be knowing about permissions etc..